# Custom list reference number

Tags: reference

I'd like to know how to use a calculated formula column to generate a custom reference number in the below format / SharePoint 2013

OIPCR-Month/Year/Unique number starting from 100

EG. OIPCR-Mar17-102

The Month and Year should be locked in at form submission.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Cheers,
Nick

Comment: Do you able to use InfoPath?

Comment: I do use Infopath Design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below formula in a calculated column

> =CONCATENATE("OIPCR-",TEXT(Created,"MMM"),TEXT(Created,"YY"),"-",(ID+99))

`Created` is the default creation (Submission) date , and the above formula uses the default `ID` column to generate a unique number and added to `99` so it will start from `100`

the results will look like   `OIPCR-Mar18-100`

Comment: @Nick welcome, glad to help :)